# What to do if I find a deleted question I just wanted to ask

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

I've just got a problem with `git gui` just like described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204388/git-gui-cannot-start-because-of-bad-version-number). Unfortunately, the question has been deleted by the OP.

There's no answer, so not much got lost... except that the OP probably knows the answer. Ideally, I'd send them a message, but I can't comment on deleted questions and there's no messaging here.

I voted to undelete, does the OP get informed automatically? The other problem is if they would care.

I could post a duplicate, but this is not optimal. Any better idea?

In the meantime I've found a hacky solution (reverting `/usr/lib/git-core/git-gui`), but I guess the OP knows better.

Comment: If they deleted it then any knowledge associated with that question is lost to you, and to anyone else. If two people have come up with the same question, and needed the answer, why is it 'less than optimal' to ask the question again?

Comment: @DavidThomas The answer is most probably still in the OP's head, so nothing is lost. The question is the only relevant hit I could Google out. Asking a new question is probably no big deal, but I'd just copy&paste it all (and as a programmer I hate copypasting). What's worse, I voted to reopen and would possible create a real duplicate.

Comment: I would say post a new question. The deleted question had no answers associated with it (even in comments) so nothing was lost by deleting it, and I think it is best to respect their decision to not be associated with that question.

Comment: If you post the question, it's possible that the original poster may respond if they have already solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Deleted questions are not relevant as duplicate targets.

But if you do ask it, you need to make it a better question than the original (if the original was deleted for "off-topic" reasons).  Otherwise, it will suffer the same fate.

Comment: "suffer the same fate"? The question in question was deleted by its poster ~90 minutes after posting. It didn't have any downvotes or even negative comments. It looks like that OP figured out what was wrong and removed their question. There's no reason to believe the exact same question couldn't be answered if posted again.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Awesome.  Do keep in mind that answers on Meta should be generally applicable, and the OP did not tag their question [meta-tag:specific-question].